# Programmatic On / Off Control of 3.3v board power

Tags: voltage, relay, opto-isolator, gpio, jtag

I'm running some tests on a board I have developed. As part of these tests I would like to run a command, then quickly (like microsecond or less time) cut the power from the board.

To perform these test on the main board, I have a JTAG/debugging board which has some general purpose GPIO pins. (My debugging board is a Goodfet42, see picture below). I would like to use a GPIO pin to turn power on and off the test board (pin high = vcc on, pin low = vcc off)

The debugging board provides the 3.3v power needed to power the board I am testing. So there is a common ground between them.

The test board requires ~50ma of current. The JTAG/debug board currently provides this.

My basic issue is that I realize I have a few different options (relay, optoisolator, some type of MOSFET, transistors, analog IC switch, etc), but I don't know which is the right option. What is a simple chip,circuit, etc. I can build to accomplish this given my current parameters? (3.3v, 50ma, very very quick on/off)?

[image: MY JTAG / Debug Board]

Edit:

The GoodFET board above is attached to the main board via an SPI interface. Main board is getting power from GoodFET. So only connections are 3.3v, GND, RESET, SCK, MOSI, MISO. GoodFET is hooked to a computer via USB. No other power, no other boards, etc.

Comment: In order to do it that fast you should use a mosfet, and possibly a driver IC to make sure the mosfet is switched quickly.

Comment: There are a lot of potential issues here. It would help a lot if you could draw a diagram showing all boards involved in this scheme, and list every connection between the boards, including USB, JTAG, SWD, whatever. My concern is this: if you cut power to a board, but you have other data connections from that board to another board which is still powered up, nothing is going to work the way you expect. If the board whose power is being cut has no IO connections (including no programmer attached) then it is OK.

Comment: @mkeith ya that was my concern too.

Comment: Since your board has decoupling capacitors on it, trying to get the power supply turnoff slope down to 1 us is going to be a challenge. The best approach may be to use a current limited power supply and use a high current FET to short it out.

Comment: I doubt you will get anything to turn on or off in 1 µs. An LED, sure, but an IC with internal RAM? (Mainly thinking about DRAM) Hmmm.. I'm not an expert, but I wouldn't get my hopes up. If I were you I would slow down the baudrate, the parameter (I believe) that forces you to switch at 1 µs. - At this point I smell something, something pungent. Something nasty. It's most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)! You're the 999 999th visitor. Congratulations. Win a free iPod.

Comment: Ok so good point about the time, 1 µs was not a hard requirement, just as fast as possible. @mkeith the GoodFET board above is attached to the main board via an SPI interface. Main board is getting power from GoodFET. So only connections are 3.3v power, GND, RESET, SCK, MOSI,MISO. No other power,   etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to turn off a 3.3V power supply is to use a logic-enable
pin on a 3.3V regulator.  This one [LP2951CM-3.3](http://www.ti.com/product/lp2951/datasheet)
would suit your application.  It can work with low output
capacitance (2.2 uF) which should allow the output to
drop below 1V in about 160uS.

That assumes that the '50 mA' current is the ONLY drain on the
output filter capacitor, but you could draw higher current
by adding a shunt transistor; it'll take circa 4A to short out
(most of) the stored energy in that capacitor if you need 1 uS response.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnZ47Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will presumably do it (but it's a bit ugly).    Turnon (like turnoff) is somewhat slowed because of the capacitor (and there may be others) as well, but maybe that isn't as important.